# Cannot update dynamically created fragment after rotation

Tags: android, android-layout, rotation, fragment, android-support-library

I have a problem with fragments and configuration changes (rotation) : I have a screen with a button that randomly update the Text of a fragment.

Everything works fine untill I rotate the device (configuration change) : I can `findFragmentByTag` the fragment but its `getView()` method returns `null`.
I'm working with setRetainState(true) : all private fields are well retaineed.

In the following code, I'm dynamically creating the fragment because I'm in the context of a view pager (TestItemListFragment refers to the fragment of a ViewPager Page and TestItemDetailFragment refers the the fragment where I want the text to be updated when clicking on the button). Though, for this example, the showed code is simplified, see comments in the code for details.

What am I missing ? What am i doing wrong ? (sure I am)

**edit :** link to the source for reproduction : https://bitbucket.org/bixibu/demo-nestedfragment-android

Activity :

```
public class TestActivity extends FragmentActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onResumeFragments() {
        super.onResumeFragments();

        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        TestItemListFragment frag = TestItemListFragment.newInstance();

        if (getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentByTag("tag") == null) {
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(android.R.id.content, frag, "tag").commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }
    }
}
```

Page Fragment :

```
public class TestItemListFragment extends Fragment {


    ItemDetailFragment detailFragment = null;
    String mCurTitle = null;

    private SecureRandom random = new SecureRandom();

    public static TestItemListFragment newInstance() {
        TestItemListFragment fragment = new TestItemListFragment();
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setRetainInstance(true);
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateView(inflater, container, savedInstanceState);
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_fragment_test, container, false);
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

        /**
         * Addind random string generation while clicking on button
         * And setting this random String to the fragment
         */
        Button button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
        button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                updateDetail(new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32));
            }
        });

        // creating new fragment
        detailFragment = ItemDetailFragment.newInstance(new Bundle());

        // in my XML I don't have any ID because I have to create as many fragment as I have Pages in my ViewPager
        // so I dynamically creates an ID
        // in order to have a different fragment for each Page
        // if I don't do that only my first Page display a fragment (or multiple ones)
        int fragmentContainerUniqId = 519618565;
        View fragmentContainer = getView().findViewById(R.id.detailFragmentContainer);
        fragmentContainer.setId(fragmentContainerUniqId);

        if (getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(fragmentContainerUniqId) == null) {
            // Add the fragment to the 'detailFragmentContainer' FrameLayout
            getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                    .add(fragmentContainerUniqId, detailFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
        }

        if (mCurTitle != null) {
            updateDetail(mCurTitle);
        }

    }

    // May also be triggered from the Activity
    public void updateDetail(String title) {
        detailFragment.setTitle(title);
    }
}
```

Detail Fragment :

```
public class ItemDetailFragment extends Fragment {

    public static ItemDetailFragment newInstance(Bundle bundle) {
        ItemDetailFragment fragment = new ItemDetailFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        return fragment;
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {

        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_detail_fragment, container, false);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onViewCreated(View view, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onViewCreated(view, savedInstanceState);

        setTitle(getArguments().getString("title"));
    }

    public void setTitle(String title) {
        if (getView() != null && title != null) {
            TextView view = (TextView) getView().findViewById(R.id.detailsText);

            view.setText(title);
        }
    }
}
```

XML :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="populate fragment"
        />


        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/detailFragmentContainer"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_weight="2" />


</LinearLayout>
```

Manifest :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.burnside.digital.nestedfragments"
    android:versionCode="1"
    android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="16" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >
        <activity
            android:name="com.burnside.digital.nestedfragments.TestActivity"
            android:label="@string/title_activity_test" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

ps: I'm working with support-v4 lib

Thanks for you help, I'll update my post i something is unclear, so let me know.

Comment: do you have configChanges declared inside your manifest.xml?

Comment: To make it clear, `TestItemListFragment` is used in a `ViewPager`?

Comment: I haven't declared any configChanges in the manifest. and yes TestItemListFragment is used in a view pager in my app. But my bug is reproducted too without it (the code showed here is enough to reproduct the bug). Thanks for the help

Comment: @blackbelt do you mean the `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden"` ? I tried it with no success

Comment: @Bixi: I see you're targetting sdk 16, so that means `screenSize` will also change when rotating the device. Try with this code in your AndroidManifest. `android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"`

Comment: @Jelle Thanks it works. But isn't it more like a hack ? My activity now doesn't restart so the bug is now hidden but already present. developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/… does not recommand this practice and I don't understand well all the impacts... Edit: behavior isn't stable and the activity is sometime recreated, so the bug reappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After screen rotation,your fragment (visible on screen) is not updated because, it's not the same fragment that detailFragment.

After screen rotation, you create a new fragment :

```
   detailFragment = ItemDetailFragment.newInstance(new Bundle());
```

but it will not be add to fragmentContainerUniqId because

```
   getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(fragmentContainerUniqId)
```

is not null

Change your code in TestItemListFragment by this and the fragment will be update

```
@Override
public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);

    /**
     * Addind random string generation while clicking on button
     * And setting this random String to the fragment
     */
    Button button = (Button) getView().findViewById(R.id.button1);
    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            updateDetail(new BigInteger(130, random).toString(32));
        }
    });


    // in my XML I don't have any ID because I have to create as many fragment as I have Pages in my ViewPager
    // so I dynamically creates an ID
    // in order to have a different fragment for each Page
    // if I don't do that only my first Page display a fragment (or multiple ones)
    int fragmentContainerUniqId = 519618565;
    View fragmentContainer = getView().findViewById(R.id.detailFragmentContainer);
    fragmentContainer.setId(fragmentContainerUniqId);

    if ((detailFragment = (ItemDetailFragment) getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(fragmentContainerUniqId)) == null) {
        // Add the fragment to the 'detailFragmentContainer' FrameLayout
        // creating new fragment
        detailFragment = ItemDetailFragment.newInstance(new Bundle());
        getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction()
                .add(fragmentContainerUniqId, detailFragment).commitAllowingStateLoss();
    }

    if (mCurTitle != null) {
        updateDetail(mCurTitle);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In PageFragment, instead of:

```
    getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
```

use:

```
    getSupportFragmentManager();
```

After rotation, the first form will still refer to the original activity.
The second form will correctly reference the newly created activity.

Comment: getSupportFragmentManager() is undefined, i have to choose either getChildFragmentManager() or getFragmentManager() but both ain't working.